# Unable to push TestFlight after updating to xcode 13

Tags: testflight, provisioning-profile, xcode13

Hello Guys I am new here I having issue related to pushing test-flight someone said me to delete profile and manually create i have no idea how to do it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Xcode 13](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev8e84490b9)

> In Xcode 13 or later, Xcode will cloud sign any apps or software for
> distribution when you’re using the Xcode Organizer archive and
> distribution workflow. Additional permissions are available in App
> Store Connect to enable Admins and Developers to sign apps and
> software with these certificates.

So you need to enable **Access to Cloud Managed Distribution Certificate** in **App Store Connect -> Users and Access** for my account, as Jane Doe said in this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688626).

And that did solve the issue.

See also:

- [Xcode 13 - Cannot Submit Archive - Errors occurred while locating signing assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69419487/xcode-13-cannot-submit-archive-errors-occurred-while-locating-signing-assets)

Comment: issue fixed but thanks for your time

Comment: @AsfandYarHafeez gr8! Is my advice correct. If yes, could you accept it as the right answer?