# Xcode 13 - Cannot Submit Archive - Errors occurred while locating signing assets

Tags: xcode, xcode13

This issue only started after updating to Xcode 13. Never had it under 12.x and no other changes. I am tying to send an Archive to Appstore Connect for a client. I have the "App Manager" role which has always been enough for this activity. However, when trying to send or even validate in Xcode, I receive an error related to "locating signing assets" with the log indicating the following:

> 2021-10-02 18:18:38 +0000 [MT] Failed to locate signing assets with
> errors: (
> "Error Domain=DeveloperAPIServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "Communication with Apple failed."
> UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=You are not allowed to perform this
> operation.  Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need
> further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support.
> https://developer.apple.com/support,
> NSLocalizedDescription=Communication with Apple failed.}",
> "Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'com.company.app' were found"
> UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription=No
> profiles for 'com.company.app' were found,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store
> provisioning profiles matching 'com.company.app'.}" )

I have tried to remove my account from Xcode and re-add, but to no effect. Again, I have had the App Manager role forever and never had a problem until upgrading to Xcode 13. I was thinking of having him elevate me to "Administrator" but that really should not be necessary. I also created a new distribution cert through Xcode (no errors there) but that didn't help either.

As an update. I went the manual route and created a profile and chose to select it manually rather than having Xcode handle it automatically. That worked. However, of course it should not have to work that way and I still don't understand why the automatic method is failing.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: It sounds from this and other posts as if something has gone wrong with Apple's new cloud based automatic distribution signing. I think you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

It seems an Apple issue with the automatic sign-in process with Xcode 13. But maybe it's a wanted behavior for Xcode 13 using cloud base certs instead of the local ones.

Here's my story looking for a solutions for this.

[image]

I can confirm that downgrade back to **Xcode 12** or switch to the **manual signing way** all works fine

Someone says that doing that:

> Switch "automatically manage signing" in the project or re-select
> Team. Make sure the changes appear in the project file:
>
> CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "Apple Development"; CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;

May solve the issue, but it didn't work for me.

It seems that [Xcode 13](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev8e84490b9)

> In Xcode 13 or later, Xcode will cloud sign any apps or software for
> distribution when you’re using the Xcode Organizer archive and
> distribution workflow. Additional permissions are available in App
> Store Connect to enable Admins and Developers to sign apps and
> software with these certificates.

So I ended up enabling **Access to Cloud Managed Distribution Certificate** in **App Store Connect -> Users and Access** for my account, as Jane Doe said in this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688626).

[image]

And that did solve the issue.

Here are all my references:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690763
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688626
- https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev8e84490b9